# Moving Files and Folders Accidentally to Non-existent Places

Tags: linux, file, directory, mv

I often do the command such as:

```
mv folder $something_that_does_not_exist
mv files* $something_that_does_not_exist
```

Then, I realise that my files are gone. I cannot see them even in the folder "$something_that_does_not_exist". Where have my files and folders gone? How can I get them back?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to prevent this problem, I have a habit of always appending a / to the end of directory names when using `cp` or `mv`:

```
$ touch foo
$ mv foo bar/
mv: cannot move `foo' to `bar/foo': No such file or directory
```

Without the trailing slash, `mv` does a file rename operation. You may find that your file(s) have changed name.

Answer (score 2):

If `$something_that_does_not_exist` expands to nothing (but I am not sure if that is your problem?) then the first mv will fail. The second mv command will also fail unless `"files*"` expand to exactly two files or if the last file name `"files*"` expands to happens to be a directory. Then the files will be moved to that directory.

If the command are in a script and you want your script to abort when trying to expand the variable and it is not set, you can use the question mark modifier. Example:

```
$ echo ${DISPLAY?}; echo display
:0.0
display
$ echo ${MYTEST?}; echo mytest
bash: MYTEST: parameter null or not set
$
```

So if you use

```
mv folder ${something_that_does_not_exist?}
```

and `something_that_does_not_exist` is not set, commands following will not be executed.

Comment: You are on the right track. The event is related to the last command. I reasoned wrong that the first thing would occur as I noticed the last thing. I am still rather confused WHY the thing happens.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to get your files back, as the shell will expand your files and I believe the last file on the list will now be called $something_that_does_not_exist.

All your other files in the list will have been overwritten. So you cannot get them back.

EDIT: On my smoothwall VM (the only GNU/Linux at my fingers right now!) I get this:

```
$ mkdir t1
$ mv t1 t2
$ ls
t2/
$ mv t2 t1
$ cd t1
$ touch f1 f2 f3 f4
$ mv f* ../t2
mv: target `../t2' is not a directory
```

Comment: Ok, my bad assumption was that $something_that_does_not_exist was something you would type, not a shell variable. As others have said, this will fail

Comment: I think is a joke question, so mv files* /dev/null is probably the better response :)

Answer (score 0):

```
mv folder $something_that_does_not_exist
```

This ought to be an error:

```
$ mkdir folder
$ mv folder
mv: Insufficient arguments (1)
Usage: mv [-f] [-i] f1 f2
       mv [-f] [-i] f1 ... fn d1
       mv [-f] [-i] d1 d2
```

The other case depends on what `files*` matched:

```
mv files* $something_that_does_not_exist
```

If the final match is a directory, you will likely find your files there.  Otherwise you will have either renamed the first file to be the same as the second or had another error as above.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** You try to move the directory "folder":

```
mv folder abcde
```

If "abcde" is an existing directory, it will move "folder" into "abcde". If "abcde" is an existing file, the command will fail. Otherwise it will rename "folder" to "abcde".

**2)** You try to move some files:

```
mv files* abcde
```

If "abcde" is an existing directory, it will move the "files*" into "abcde". Otherwise, if there is only one file matching "files*", it will rename that file to "abcde". Otherwise the command will fail.